# Как добавить отсортированный текст в поле sql

Tags: sql, kotlin

Прошу, помогите! 
Как сделать так чтобы при взятие текста из база данных выводилось отсортировано? Например:
Репетиторам на страницу регистрации можно перейти двумя способами:

1. Нажать ссылку "Стать репетитором" в самой нижней части главной
   страницы сайта
2. Нажать кнопку "Регистрация" в главном меню сайта, которая находится
   в верхней части экрана. Далее выбрать тип профиля - Репетитор.

Далее в обязательном порядке заполнить все поля формы, и обратить внимание на то, что при добавлении университета, предмета преподавания и языка преподавания нужно нажимать кнопку "+" (Плюс), чтобы выбранный элемент добавился. Фотография профиля и сканы/копии сертификатов/дипломов не обязательны, но желательно их загрузить для привлечения родителей и учеников. По завершении регистрации на указанную Вами электронную почту будет отправлено письмо с подтверждением. Обязательно подтвердите электронную почту для авторизации на сайте.

Comment: 2. был с новой строки

Comment: Вопросу срочно требуется редактор

Comment: Редактор тут не поможет. Вопрос не содержит вопроса, как бы странно тут не звучало. Какое поле отсортировать, зачем...

Comment: Дмитрий когда из таблицы хочу вывести то 2.пункт не начинается с начоло строки я надеюсь вы поняли

Comment: если у вас проблемы с кодом, в вопросе должен быть этот код, а не описание его работы.